# How to clear the value of an input field in a functional component without using state?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-functional-component

I have an input field and I handle the input via onKeyUp (as I need to access `event.which`). This works great so far as I just grab the content of the input via `event.target.value` but I run into issues when I try to reset the value of the input field.

I'm using functional components, so accessing the input via refs isn't possible and all examples I found with useRef just show how to focus the input field but not how to clear it.

I forgot to mention that I'm using Material-UI.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can clear an input's value with a ref inside a functional component by setting `ref.current.value` imperatively to an empty string:

```
const App = () => {
  const textInput = React.useRef();

  const clearInput = () => (textInput.current.value = "");

  return (
    <>
      <input type="text" ref={textInput} />
      <button onClick={clearInput}>Reset</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Is it only possible to clear it via events (e.g. onClick)? I would need to clear it in my "handleInput" method that gets called "onKeyUp"

Comment: Not at all. You can repeat this code anywhere you need it, it's just setting the value of a property: ```textInput.current.value = ""```

Comment: I think my problem was caused by the MaterialUI textfield, switching to a simple input field worked as you mentioned. I needed to make the switch as the performance of the textfield was a lot slower than the simple input.

Answer (score 3):

My current solution uses onChange to update the state of the value and onKeyUp to handle the input (and eventually resetting the value):

```
export default function TypingArea() {
const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState('');

const handleChange = event => {
  setInputValue(event.target.value);
};

const handleInput = event => {
  // access event.which for the keycode and eventually clear the inputfield value
  setInputValue('');
}  

return (
<TextField
  onChange={handleChange}
  onKeyUp={handleInput}
  type='text'
  value={inputValue} />);
}
```

I might run into issues with this setup as I'm not sure who runs first, onChange or onKeyUp, but it works for now.

Answer (score 0):

you can do e.target.reset considering you are using functional component.

```
 const [state, setState] = React.useState({ username: "", password: "" });

  const handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(state);
```

> e.target.reset();

```
  };
const handleChange = e => {
    setState({
      ...state,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    });
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Log In</h1>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input
          className="userInput"
          name="username"
          type="text"
          placeholder="username"
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
        <br />
        <input
          className="userInput"
          name="password"
          type="password"
          placeholder="password"
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
        <br />
        <input className="userSubmit" type="submit" value="Log In" />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([]);
const [input, setInput] = useState(' ');


Const addTask = () => {
       setTasks([...tasks, input])
       SetInput(' ')

}
return (
  <button onClick={addTasks}/>Add Task <button/>
)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please read "[answer]" and "[Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". It helps more if you supply an explanation why this is the preferred solution and explain how it works. We want to educate, not just provide code.